# .gitignore style fnmatch()

Tags: python, regex, filenames, gitignore, fnmatch

What would be the simplest way to have .gitignore style fnmatch() with Python. Looks like that stdlib does not provide a match() function which would match a path spec against an UNIX style path regex.

- fnmatch() matches only pure filenames, no paths http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html?highlight=fnmatch#fnmatch
- glob() will perform directory listing, and does not provide match() true/false style function http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob

.gitignore have both paths and files with wildcards to be (black)listed

- https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/.gitignore
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore

Comment: Why do regular expression not work for you?

Comment: I prefer to accept only valid answers.

Comment: Maybe I ask too hard questions? :)

Comment: I guess you could look at it that way, or just having unrealistic expectations. Some of your questions get good activity, some don't. And you have also had some down-voted or closed; A mixed bag really. It just really does motivate people to interact with your questions in this community when they know you are the type of person that can be helped. Whats the point of trying to offer answers if nothing will please you?

Comment: Found an example GPL2 implementation here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bzr-pqm/bzr/bzr.dev/view/head:/bzrlib/globbing.py

Comment: I am not looking for amusement or karma, I am looking for answers. Correct answers will be accepted and I hope people will be up to that before even trying, so that I don't need to shamelessly downvote bad/incorrect answers. Good answers = good karma :)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa  Consider changing the accepted answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use mixed UNIX wildcard patterns as listed in your .gitignore example, why not just take each pattern and use `fnmatch.translate` with `re.search`?

```
import fnmatch
import re

s = '/path/eggs/foo/bar'
pattern = "eggs/*"

re.search(fnmatch.translate(pattern), s)
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10049e988>
```

`translate` turns the wildcard pattern into a re pattern

Hidden UNIX files:

```
s = '/path/to/hidden/.file'
isHiddenFile = re.search(fnmatch.translate('.*'), s)
if not isHiddenFile:
    # do something with it
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails with such a simple fnmatch pattern like .* (ignore all UNIX hidden files).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: I'm not sure I follow. My update shows that it properly matches a path to a hidden unix file.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Yea I give up. I don't get the correlations. Good luck!

Comment: But you were on very right track - bug is more like deeper issue with Python fnmatch() itself. I'll mark this closed and leave this link for the future generationsto https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/tree/master/vvv/bzrlib as the solution.

Answer (score 25):

There's a library called [pathspec](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathspec) which implements the full `.gitignore` specification, including things like `**/*.py`; the [documentation](http://python-path-specification.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) describes how to handle Git pattern matching (you can also see [code](https://github.com/cpburnz/python-path-specification/blob/master/pathspec/patterns/gitwildmatch.py)).

```
>>> import pathspec
>>> spec_src = '**/*.pyc'
>>> spec = pathspec.PathSpec.from_lines(pathspec.patterns.GitWildMatchPattern, spec_src.splitlines())
>>> set(spec.match_files({"test.py", "test.pyc", "deeper/file.pyc", "even/deeper/file.pyc"}))
set(['test.pyc', 'even/deeper/file.pyc', 'deeper/file.pyc'])
>>> set(spec.match_tree("pathspec/"))
set(['__init__.pyc', 'gitignore.pyc', 'util.pyc', 'pattern.pyc', 'tests/__init__.pyc', 'tests/test_gitignore.pyc', 'compat.pyc', 'pathspec.pyc'])
```